# how to change geojson search parameters from html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, geojson

I made a geojson file using php from a database, but I need to be able to change the query parameters using a form from the main page, here is the form and the loaded json file:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <div class="form">
                <form method="get"> 
                    <input type="text" name="number" id="number"  placeholder="to"  >
                    <input type="text" name="startDate" id="sDate"  placeholder="From"  >
                    <input type="text" name="endDate" id="eDate" placeholder="till"><br/>
                    <input type="submit" name="Search" id="Search" value="Search">
                </form> 
            </div>
            <script>
                var geoJsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "json2.php",
                    dataType: "json",

                    success: console.log("succes"),
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert("Json error")
                    }
                })

               </script>
```

and here is the query from the geojson file(json2.php):

```
$number = $_GET['number'];

$startD = date('d.m.Y');
 $endD = date('d.m.Y');

$startData = strtotime($startD . '00:00:00');
$pgsqlstartdata = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $startData);

$endData = strtotime($endD . '23:59:59');
 $pgsqlenddata = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $endData);

 $query = pg_query($connect, "SELECT number, state, date, lat,long "
    . "FROM schema.table "
    . "WHERE number = '$number' AND "
    . "data BETWEEN '$pgsqlstartdata' and '$pgsqlenddata' order by data asc limit 100 ");
```

when i try to include the json fle to the form file its giving me parese error because the form its not json format, so anyone has any ideea how to send the parameters?

Comment: Just so you know, you can simplify your date variables by using `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("today"))` and `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("tomorrow"))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to accomplish, but if the goal is to pass the form to PHP as json, then you need to use the serialize() function. Also, you are not currently passing any data with your AJAX call. Let's fix that.

First, change your form method to post and add an id to your form so we can access it directly:

```
<form method="post" id="geoform">
```

Next, change the first rows in your AJAX call:

```
var geoJsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "json2.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",
    data: $("#geoform").serialize(),
```

Finally, deserialize and output the form in PHP so you can see what you're working with:

```
<?php
    $formData = json_decode($_POST);
    var_dump($formData);
```

Comment: I need to send  a new number parameter, to change the parameter in the select query and i need to do that from the form , hope you can understand what im saying, thx for the help :D

Comment: Oh. That might be a fair bit simpler, since your original code almost does just that. If you don't mind the page reloading you can just change the original form tag to this: <form method="get" action="json2.php">

Comment: Of course, if you are using the geoJsonData variable, then you probably won't see any difference, since that call ignores the contents of your form.

Comment: Thank you very much cant belive it was that simple :D

Comment: When im using the action its sends me on the json file, and showing me the json results and i dont want to be redirected to that page

Comment: Then you have a couple of options. You can either do a header('Location: PageYouWantToGoTo.php'); in PHP to redirect to the page you want to be on, or you can fix your AJAX call so that it submits the form for you and stops the regular submission (so the page isn't reloaded). The first one is self-explanatory, but feel free to ask me if you need help with the latter.

Comment: Yes the ajax call seems to do the work, thank you for your time